# How can I say, "are you free to meet sometime soon" in a friendly and informal way?

Tags: choix-de-mot, phrase

> Es-tu libre de te rencontrer un jour ou l'autre ?

sounds simply wrong, stiff or somehow 'unfrench' to me...
In this context, I would be meeting a friend for a regularly occurring chat over coffee.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, as soon as you're "friendly and informal", you should drop inversions. So "*es-tu libre*" should be "*tu es libre*".

Then, you should use "*se rencontrer*", instead of "*te rencontrer*". Phrased like this, "*es-tu libre de **te** rencontrer*" means "*are you free to meet yourself?*", because *tu* is the subject. You'd have to use *se rencontrer*, but then the subject has to be "we". Something like "Are you free sometime soon, **so that we** could meet?".

Lastly, it depends on what you mean by "meet". If you mean meet as in see someone in person for the first time, it will be:

> On peut se rencontrer un de ces jours ?

> T'es libre pour qu'on se rencontre un de ces quatre ?

But if you mean "meet" like just see a person you already know, you'd use "se voir". It would be something like:

> T'es libre pour qu'on se voie un de ces jours ?

> Tu serais dispo pour se voir un de ces quatre ?

Comment: Can you explain "de ces quatre"? I'm unfamiliar with that (presumably informal) phrase.

Comment: Tu as des disponibilités (dispos) pour qu'on se voit ?

Comment: @WaterMolecule It simply means "one of these days", "someday soon".

Comment: @WaterMolecule I'm completing Teleporting Goat comment : "un de ces quatre" is an expression that originates from "un de ce quatres matins", literally translated to "one of the next four mornings". This is used an expression to say "someday soon"

Comment: *Un de ces quatre* is a bit old-fashioned. You would not use it under, say, 30 yo (source: I checked with my teen children and a ~30 yo friend). I would rather use the previously mentioned *un de ces jours*

Answer (score 3):

*Es-tu libre de te rencontrer* doesn't make sense. That means the person would meet themself. The sentence should have been:

> *Es-tu libre **pour me** rencontrer un jour ou l'autre ?*

Here are other ways to say it:

> Est-ce que tu es libre pour qu'on se voie un de ces quatre ?

> Tu es dispo pour qu'on se retrouve de temps en temps autour d'un café ?

Answer (score 2):

"Es-tu libre de te rencontrer un jour ou l'autre ?" is not correct. The verb is the verb "se rencontrer", a pronominal verb; however, there is more than one sort of pronominal verbs; you are confusing the pronominal verb of type called "sens réfléchi" (action on yourself)  with the pronominal verb of type "sens réciproque" (action on one another). Here is some [study material](https://www.dys-positif.fr/les-differents-types-de-verbes-pronominaux-4eme/). As it is of the  type called "sens reciproque", the subject and the pronoun are in the plural.

- As-tu du temps libre pour que nous nous rencontrions un jour ou l'autre ?

Note that "un jour ou l'autre" does *not* entail the possibility of several times, but that of only one time.

*A few  options*

- On pourrait peut-être s'arranger pour nous rencontrer de temps à autre, dans un café ou ailleurs ?
- Tu aurais du temps libre pour des rencontres de temps en temps ?
- On pourrait peut-être se rencontrer quelque fois, le temps d'un café, si tu as du temps libre.
- Si le temps n'est pas un problème pour toi, pourquoi ne pas se rencontrer certains jours, le temps d'un café.

Comment: On pourrait peut-être se rencontrer quelque fois. Maybe we could meet a few times?

Comment: Not one of your suggestions translates the idea: Are you free to meet sometime. It is not: Do you have free time (temps libre); it's are you free: es-tu libre. It's not anger, it's disagreement over mistranslation. jlliagre and Teleporting Goat got it right. Therefore, I don't think it deserved to me selected as accurate.

Comment: @Lambie "on pourrait peut être se rencontrer quelque fois." est faussé par l'usage du quelque fois. D'une part le texte original est sometime soon (pour moi il n'y a pas de multiplicité de rencontres demandées), d'autre part, on dirait plutôt 2- 3 fois, ponctuellement, IMHO.

Comment: @Poutrathor  An s was missing in my answer, sorry.

Comment: @Lambie "meet me", meet them", … that is right now, after you add a pronoun!

Comment: @LPH **Not at all**: "Are you free to meet this afternoon"? A pronoun is not necessary at all.

Comment: @Lambie I believe you, but it is found only for the last twenty years (as you can check from the page of examples, and I don't like it anyway; it doesn't sound idiomatic.

Comment: @LPH You are mistaken.  Look at the google page I gave you. It ain't recent. [only found **in the last twenty years**].

Comment: @Lambie Spoken language gets into the books because books reproduce this language in  dialogues. If you do not find it in the books, often it means that it hasn't been used in everyday language.

Comment: "_pour que nous nous rencontriions_" -> obviously an extra "i". And this probably a bit extreme for "friendly and informal".

Comment: @jcaron Il y a bien un i de trop. // Vérifier la locution « pour que » : http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238 //Il est nécessaire d'utiliser le subjonctif. // Je suis bien d'accord qu'un autre temps, come le présent de l'indicatif  par exemple, peut parfois être acceptable, dans certain cas, mais pas dans celui-ci. // L'utilisation du subjonctif n'est pas en français une question de formalité,  n'est pas une question d'enjolivement du langage dont on se débarrasserait dès que l'on n'a plus à faire impression. C'est une caractéristique (« feature » en anglais) qui (1/2)

Comment: @jcaron sert à représenter ce qui n'est pas actuel dans la situation, et que l'utilisateur du langage qui a acquis assez d'expérience perçois comme étant essentielle. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Your context makes me wonder:
*i would be meeting a friend for a **regularly** occurring chat over coffee.*
You can say :
**y a t'il un jour qui t'arrangerait pour se rencontrer ?**
But the answer could be:
***Oui, le mardi***  (*jour* a été compris comme *un jour de la semaine chaque semaine*)  ou alors:
***Oui, le mardi 15*** (*jour* a été compris comme *un de ces jours* ).

It's better to be precise :
**Quel jour de semaine pourrait-on se rencontrer ?**    (Regularly).

**Est-ce qu'on peut se voir un de ces jours ?** (One meeting soon)

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

> On peut se voir un de ces jours si t'es libre.

or

> Dis-moi si tu es (or t'es) libre pour se voir (or se revoir if you are seeing them again)

or

> Est-ce que tu veux qu'on se voie pour prendre un café et tchatcher

or

> Est-ce que ça te dit de se voir régulièrement pour discuter ensemble (if you want to stress the repeated nature of the request).

*Est-ce que* isn't formal in this case, it's very idiomatic and sounds more natural than saying *veux-tu* or *es-tu*

Answer (score 0):

> Es-tu libre/disponible (prochainement) pour qu'on se rencontre (bientôt) ?